# JavaScript - make object from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 3 arrays:

```
colors = ['green', 'red', 'black'];
positionToId = [0, 32, 15];
results = ["0", "1", "2"];
```

And want to achieve something like this:

```
{results: '0', 'positionToId: '31', colors: 'black'},
{results: '1', 'positionToId: '2', colors: 'red'},
{results: '2', 'positionToId: '11', colors: 'black'}
```

How can I do that? 
Thanks.

Comment: Please do not include code as an image.  Include code as code.  Also, what have you done so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: moved image to code in the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an array of objects from multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539591/how-to-create-an-array-of-objects-from-multiple-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to merge these arrays into an array of objects with `key => value`.

Easiest way is to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) one of them.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Example:

```js
colors = ['green', 'red', 'black'];
positionToId = [0, 32, 15];
results = ["0", "1", "2"];


console.log(results.map((result,i) => {
  return {
    results: results[i], 
    positionToId: positionToId[i],
    colors: colors[i],
  };
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an array `results` that you seem to want to use as your base and you want to replace these numbers, with objects keyed by the values already there I would just reduce them.

```
colors = ['green', 'red', 'black'];
positionToId = [0, 32, 15];
results = ["0", "1", "2"];

const newObject = results.reduce((acc, index) => ({
    ...acc,
    [index]: {
        positionToId: positionToId[index],
        colors: colors[index],
    }
}), {})
```

This also has the benefit of allowing you to access your items by id without having to loop over an array checking each of the id's

Answer (score 0):

```js
const colors = ['green', 'red', 'black'];
const positionToId = [0, 32, 15];
const results = ["0", "1", "2"];

const addProperties = (properties, name, results) => properties.reduce((results, property, index) => {
  results[index][name] = property;
  return results;
}, results);

let output = Array.from(Array(3), () => ({}));

addProperties(colors, 'colors', output);
addProperties(positionToId, 'positionToId', output);
addProperties(results, 'results', output);

console.log(output)
```